# Object() takes no Parameters ; however, __init__() exists

Tags: python, pymongo, crud

I am working in a Jupyter notebook trying to implement simple CRUD operations for a collection using Pymongo.  The code for the CRUD class so far is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init_(self, username, password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:54933' % (username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
            
# Create method to implement the R in CRUD. 
    def read(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animal.find(data)
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to find, because data parameter is empty")
```

The code for the main py file is:

```
from module4_markw import AnimalShelter


def main():
    username = 'aacuser'
    password = 'acc355!'
    aShelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
    data = [""]
    aShelter.create(data)
    aShelter.read(data)
```

When I run main, however, I get an "Object() takes no parameters" message. I'm not really sure what is causing this.  Others posts have stated that this means that their is no init() in the class code, but this is definitely there.  This error did occur after I reset the kernel in Jupyter, so something may have gone awry during that.  Thanks!

Comment: You have `__init_`. Add another underscore for `__init__`.

Answer (score 4):

Typo:

```
__init_
```

Put another underscore

Comment: If it's a typo, just post a comment and vote to close.

Comment: Apologies, I tried to find the correct option but couldn't.